# filetype specific autocommand vs after/ftplugin in lua configuration?

Tags: autocmd, lua

Is there any reason advantage (esp using lua) to put filetype specific settings in an autocmd vs putting in after/ftplugin?

Answer (score 1):

Lazyness? Internally, ftplugin works by same autocmd, so the only difference is that it uses standard augroups that are governed by "filetype on/off" commands, while your custom augroups/autocmds are not.

Another point to note, is the declaration (and, also, execution) order. If you don't have "filetype plugin indent on" in your (neovim) init script then ftplugin scripts will be registered *after* all your init commands. That's neither good nor bad. Just something to remember of.

Also, we are speaking of "filetype" stuff only. Not about catching BufRead, which is rather a wrong idea, as filetype can differ from extension way too often.

Comment: Thank you for this info.

Answer (score 1):

The only advantage I can see is putting everything in one file. Some people claim this makes it easy to transfer to other systems. I `git clone` my setup, or in rare cases transfer a tarball or zipfile of the repository.

I can see several disadvantages:

- Programming inside autocommands is hard due to syntax. Typically the solution is to write and call a function instead. But that’s more clutter.
- Separating out ftplugin-type commands from indent-type commands and other things may be difficult if not possible. Since most people presumably use `:filetype plugin indent on`, this is a small issue but one that makes trying certain combinations of settings hard. But it is more performant to separate them if you are among the few who chooses not to enable either of ftplugins or indent scripts.
- What about regular plugin scripts, compiler plugins, syntax files, ftdetect scripts, and autoload scripts (you are using autoload, aren’t you?)? All of these are in separate files anyway. What’s a few more?
- As Matt points out, it duplicates the existing mechanism but with confusing timing.
- Setting `b:undo_` variables properly is easier when all the changes for a particular filetype are in the same small file. Arguably this is true for small functions, too, but there’s already enough in my vimrc distracting from the current line(s) of code.
- Commands like scriptease’s `:Vedit ftplugin/make.vim` won’t work to show me all the filetype-specific code in an autocommand-heavy setup. Autocommands don’t show up at all, nor does the vimrc. Tracking down changes becomes a game of `:verbose` and guesswork.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.